# javascript new keyword and memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, memory-leaks, new-operator

```
let x = new MyClass();
...[more code]
let x = new MyClass();
```

Will the first instance of MyClass get garbaged collected automatically?  Or do I need to explicitly `x = null` or something like that before the second assignment, in order to avoid a memory leak?

Comment: Why would assigning `x` to `null` be different from assigning `x` to anything else?

Comment: let is block-scoped. therefore it's intended to be created, used, and destroyed in a block of code. It's designed to help control memory usage. So I am curious how you are attempting to use this variable in a way that would lead to memory issues.

Comment: I'm new to js, coming from c++.  From my background it is a natural question.  If a variable is assigned to an object on the heap, then pointed at another object without first explicitly freeing the first object, the first object is leaked.  I just want to know if js is similar, or can I truly relax and not worry about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavScript's memory is managed automatically, so objects that are deemed "unreachable" are collected by the [garbage collector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Garbage_collection).

In the example you provided, the object stored in `x` will be garbage-collected so long as it isn't reachable from other parts of your code (i.e. if you placed it in global scope in the `...[more code]` lines, the object would not be collected as it is still reachable).

Most of the time, you don't have to worry about explicit memory management in JavaScript, however it is important to know common cases where it does matter (see [4 common leaks](https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/)).

As a practical example, in most front-end frameworks/libraries, it's important to destroy `setInterval`s created by short-lived components of your app (i.e. destroying a countdown clock's interval when that countdown clock has been removed from the DOM) as the closure in these intervals could prevent objects from being collected.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.  The article is very informative also.